# Centered button is using the whole line

Tags: html, css

So, I'm pretty newbie and don't really know how to do this.

I am trying to create a main menu with a few buttons. I used center, padding and margin. (Not really sure if matters). I just noticed that the button is center (obviously), but the clickable thing is on the whole line of the button:

[image]

(Don't look at the text, it's not in English). I can click that whole thing until the button. Even after, the whole line before and after the button is clickable.
How can I fix it?

```
    .button {
      border: solid;
      border-color: darkblue;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 15px;
      margin: 1px 1px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: rgba(90, 203, 255, 0.979);
      border: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
```

That's the button parameters and that's the button itself:

```
        <a href="keks">
            <center><button class="button">Кекс</button>
            </center>
          </a></tr>
```

Comment: You cannot have a `button` in an `a`. Nesting interactive (clickable) elements is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the whole line is clickable is that you have wrapped your `<button>` inside another clickable element `<a href="keks">`.

That is not allowed. Interactive elements (that have a click default behaviour) cannot contain other interactive elements.

Also note that HTML does not have an element `<center>`. The old center element has been marked obsolete and removed from the specification decades ago.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
.button {
border: solid;
border-color: darkblue;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
margin: 1px 1px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: rgba(90, 203, 255, 0.979);
border: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 20px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<a href="keks" class="button">Kekc</a>
<!--OR-->
<button class="button" onclick="window.location.href=('kekc')">Кекс</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the center tag inside the anchor tag and place it outside the anchor tag.

```
<center>
 <a href="keks" class="button">
  Кекс
 </a>
</center>
```

Since you are using the center tag inside the anchor tag is conisdering the whole area to be a clickable.

Comment: You cannot have a `button` in an `a`. Nesting interactive (clickable) elements is not allowed.

Comment: You have corrected part of the HTML invalidity. Unfortunately your answer is still wrong as has nothing to do with the problem.